# How to send long SMS in Android?

Tags: android, encryption

I'm using RSA Encryption with a key of 1024bit , the ciphered text's length will be more than 160 bytes , and on sending an SMS of more than 160bytes it gives exception and after using sendmultisms() and divide the message , at the receiver side gets unprintable characters and also I will have a problem of how to concatandenate the SMSs.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [data-sms](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendDataMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20short,%20byte%5b%5d,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) which supports true 8bit, whereass a normal sms only takes 7bit. This is why you get garbage on the other side without any further encoding efforts.

Comment: What should be the port number ?  it throws an exception

Comment: Ask a new question about that and include the exception you got.

Answer (score 1):

You can also encode the ciphered text using Base64 encoding, break it up the into an ArrayList of Strings and use  sendMultipartTextMessage. It then sends as many SMS as needed.

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(base64EncodedMessage);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
```

Comment: I did that way but it at the receiver end it receives unprintable characters

Comment: Did you realy use base64 as encoding?

Comment: just try it on device it's work fine. I also get this kind of junk character in emulator but on device work fine.